# Capital letters to cells in column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to change all letters into capital letters in all cells holding data in column B2 and down. Got this VBA.

```
Sub CapitalLettersColumnB()

    'Capital Letters to names in column B (from B2 and down)
    'Column B holds headers!

    With Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        .Value = Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address(External:=True) & "),)")
    End With

End Sub
```

When my sheet holds 2 rows of data (and more), not counting headers, the vba works just fine.
But when my sheet only holds 1 row of data, not counting headers, name in column B (cell B2) is replaced with **#VALUE!**.
Anyone that can help spot what's wrong, and how to correct my vba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `INDEX`. The funtion returns a position in a `Range` or `Array`, not a single value. If you would evaluate the formula it would come down to this:

```
=INDEX("VALUE",)
```

Instead of a correct:

```
=INDEX({"VALUE1","VALUE2"},)
```

Not feeding the `INDEX` a range or array will then return the error

---

To correct your code you need to make sure there is always a range object larger than one cell, so for example:

```
Sub CapitalLettersColumnB()

With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    .Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & .Address & ")>1,INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address & "),)," & .Address & ")")
End With

End Sub
```

This will now work from `B1` onwards, but will leave that cell intact through the `ROW` test in our `IF` statement.

Another small note, I would definately use an explicit cell reference (including at least a worksheet)

Comment: Your code works just great. Thanks a lot for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly not sure what is wrong. (I think it's the same reason as range("B2:B2"). You can't set a range spanning the same cell)
Your `Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)` returns the value of the last cell which I'm not sure how that works.
But you could change the code to do a with the range to lastrow.
But if the lastrow is 2 the code will fail, so the if goes to else and it only changes the Ucase of cell B2.

```
If Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row > 2 Then
    ' more than one row after B2
    With Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Value = Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address(external:=True) & "),)")
    End With
Else
    ' no rows past B2
    Range("B2").Value = UCase(Range("B2").Value)
End If
```

Comment: This code works just great as well. Bit of luxury this, I've received two answers to my request, and they both solve my problem! Thanks a lot for helping out.